# How do I handle environment configuration in react-native to point at DEV/TEST/Production

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to RN and trying to figure out how I can utilize environment specific configuration.

For example, the code I have hitting my Server API needs to change based on the environment

```
const endpoint = "http://localhost:8282/api/v1/auth/"
//staging endpoint "http://staging:8282/api/v1/auth"
//production endpoint "http://production:8282/api/v1/auth"

    export default {
      login(fbId,fbAccessToken,expiresIn){
        return fetch(endpoint + 'login', {
          method: 'post',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            fb_id: fbId.toString(),
            access_token:fbAccessToken,
            expires:expiresIn.toString()
          })
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of [`__DEV__`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.32/docs/javascript-environment.html#polyfills) in order to achieve that.

Your code should look like this

```
const endpoint = __DEV__  ? "http://staging:8282/api/v1/auth/"
                          : "http://production:8282/api/v1/auth"
```